# Metaclass to make class methods the default?

Tags: python, metaclass, class-method

Is there a way to write a metaclass such that all the methods defined in classes based on this metaclass are class methods by default (i.e. without requiring, e.g., `@classmethod` decorations, etc.)?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm interested in Python 2.7.3.  Please pardon the omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this  (2.7)

```
def m(name, bases, dct):
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if type(v) is type(m):
            dct[k] = classmethod(v)
    return type(name, bases, dct)

class A:
    __metaclass__ = m

    def foo(self):
        print self


A.foo() # <class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: The canonical way to check for a function would be `if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):`. This would also be better if you used more meaningful names than `m`, `k`, and `v`.

Comment: @agf: I don't believe in spells.

Comment: I have no idea what that comment is supposed to mean. Suppose I rename the metaclass function; your code breaks. Suppose I switch it to use a class that inherits from `type` instead of a function; your code breaks. That's why you use the actual type you mean instead of finding it indirectly. And using meaningful names, especially when explaining something to someone, is basic common sense.

Comment: Well, now you're aware of that and know how to fix it if you break it. ;) In python there's no need to type cryptic constructs that should protect you from troubles that are never going to happen.

Comment: There's nothing cryptic about `if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):`. Read it. "if v is an instance of the type that functions are". Your version reads "if the type of v is the same object as the type of m" so the fact that you're talking about the type of functions isn't explicit. Using `isinstance` is also the standard and so should be preferred unless there is a good reason to use something different.

Comment: @arg: I believe the OP will be able to adapt my function to their needs. We're sharing ideas here, not chunks of production-ready code.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The real question is why you'd want to do this. I'm going to assume this is for education only. In reality, whatever this could be used for is probably better done explicitly (i.e. not using a metaclass and adding `@classmethod`).

I'm aware of two options: A custom namespace for the class definition, and post-processing in `__new__`. The first is quite cool and actually unavoidable for some cases (e.g. remembering the order of method definitions), but the latter is simpler, more flexible, can't accidentally break multiple assignments to the same name, and is available in Python 2. For your purpose, this rules out the former, but I'll leave it in for everyone who *can* use Python 3.

To supply a custom namespace, you have to define `__prepare__` in the metaclass and return a dictionary-like object (Ferdinand Beyer noted in a comment: the mapping interface as defined in `collections` is sufficent). In this case, the dictionary should override `__setitem__` to check if the value is `callable`, and if so, wrap it in `classmethod` prior to storing it. I owe a lot to the comments below, they vastly improved the code below. Ferdinand Beyer notices that `callable(classmethod(...))` is false, and agf pointed out inconsistencies with `@classmethod` and Python 3 compatability.

```
import types

# Either this, in a dictionary class instanciated in __prepare__
# Again, Python 3 only
def __setitem__(self, name, value):
    if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
        value = classmethod(value)
    super().__setitem__(name, value)

# __prepare__ would be: return AutomaticClassMethodNamespace() or something

# Or this in the metaclass
def __new__(mcls, clsname, bases, ns):
    for name, value in ns.items():
        if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
            ns[name] = classmethod(value)
    # Any other metaclass behaviour
```

Comment: You should specifically be using `types.FunctionType` not `callable`. You also mean `and not`. I'm not sure how using `__new__` in a metaclass messes up multiple definitions of the same name, since it gets a dictionary where each identifier has already been resolved to a single value?

Comment: For the record: The object returned by `__prepare__` is not required to inherit from `dict`, it only has to "support the mapping interface" (for example, using the `collections.MutableMapping` abstract base class).  See http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Comment: Since instances of `classmethod` are not callable, you don't need the extra check.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer This still tries to `classmethod` callables that aren't functions.

Comment: @agf: That's right.  I was just commenting on the "infinite recursion" (?) bit.  I would probably go for your solution, but whether to use `callable` or check for `FunctionType` ultimately is a matter of taste...

Comment: @agf Thanks for your feedback. But why wouldn't I use `callable` and include non-function callables? I'm not sure if that's consistent with the rules by which Python adds bound methods, though I'd still consider it useful (not to mention simpler to code). As for breaking multiple definitions of the same name: That may only happen if `__prepare__().__setitem__` is sloppy, and the route using `__new__` is indeed safe from it. I'd say my answer says exactly that, but I'm no native speaker - could you suggest a better phrasing?

Comment: @delnan My mistake, I read "can't" as "can" as far as messing up multiple assignments. `classmethod` specifically states it is only to be used on functions, not on any type of callable. If you try it on another callable object, it'll get implicitly passed the class object as the first argument, which seems to me to be never correct. What if there is a class defined within the class? It will raise an error when you try to instantiate it. Your code also only works on Python 3.2+ because it depends on `__prepare__` with is Python 3 only and `callable` which was removed in Python 3.0-3.1.

Comment: @agf Good points, and thanks for pointing out that `__prepare__` is 3.x only (I don't use 2.x much anymore).